# What are the implications of staying with Material-UI 0.20.1?

Tags: material-ui

Our frontend was built using Material-UI 0.18.7, and we realize that this is now very out of date.  Our frontend guy is telling me that it would be nearly a total rewrite to upgrade to a 3.x release (and our frontend is large and complex) and we just aren't able to undertake that at this time. Beyond the obvious problems that come with a very old version, are there any special issues that would be caused by not upgrading?

Answer (score 0):

Well since this is a front-end library, there is not much issues concerning security - which would be one of the main reason to upgrade.

You can see their [changelog](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/next/CHANGELOG.md) and search for keywords like 'security', 'patch' or w/e.

Of course the big reason to upgrade would be to get new features, more optimized solutions (if you are experiencing slow downs), bug fixes and much more.

Depending on the size of your front-end, it might be worth checking how much time it would actually take to upgrade.

Don't forget to take in consideration the time your front-end guy would need to implement new requested features which are already implemented on new versions, him needing to make dirty hacks to go through some known bugs, use other old libraries, etc... if you keep the old version.